# ASP.NET MVC data-val attribute for unobtrusive validation not present

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I am struggling for hours trying to understand WHY my rendered input elements within form DON'T include the data-val attributes anymore.
The environment is MVC 5 and .net framework 4.5 (I upgraded from MVC 4 hoping to solve the problem!)

An example of one of the fields being rendered:

```
<input id="UserName" class="text-box single-line" type="text" value="" name="UserName">
</input>
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="UserName"></span>
```

my model:

```
 public class AccountRegistrationValidation
    {
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationStrings))]
    [System.Web.Mvc.Remote("UsernameInUse", "Account", HttpMethod = "POST",
            ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationStrings), ErrorMessageResourceName = "UsernameExists")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationStrings))]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessageResourceName = "PasswordMinLength", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationStrings), MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationStrings))]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [System.Web.Mvc.Compare("Password", ErrorMessageResourceName = "PasswordsMustMatch", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationStrings))]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationStrings))]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [System.Web.Mvc.Remote("EmailInUse", "Account", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "Email address already exists. Please enter a different address.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationStrings))]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationStrings))]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

The View Form:

```
@model Test.Models.AccountRegistrationValidation
@using CaptchaMvc.HtmlHelpers
@{
    ViewBag.Title = ViewRes.RegisterStrings.RegisterTitle;

}



<div class="container">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>@ViewBag.Title <br /><small>@ViewRes.RegisterStrings.RegisterSubTitle</small></h1>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span7">


@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <fieldset>
        <legend>@ViewRes.RegisterStrings.FillInFields</legend>

       <div>
            <p class="text-info"><i>@ViewRes.RegisterStrings.ALL_FIELDS_REQ</i></p>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group"> 
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div class="controls">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
            </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName, new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div class="controls">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName)

            </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LastName)
        </div> 

        <div class="control-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div class="controls">
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.UserName)
                  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div class="controls">
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)

            </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div class="controls">
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)

            </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div class="controls">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)

            </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
        </div> 


        <div class="control-group"> 
            <label class="control-label" for="Input">@ViewRes.RegisterStrings.SEC_CONTROL</label>
            <div class="controls">
                @Html.Captcha(ViewRes.RegisterStrings.REFRESH_CAPTCHA, "Input", 5, "Is required field.")
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="control-group"> 
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="submit" value="@ViewRes.RegisterStrings.ButRegister" class="btn btn-success btn-large" />
            </div>
        </div>  
    </fieldset>
}

    </div>
    <div class="span1">
    </div>

</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="muted"><small>@Html.Raw(ViewRes.RegisterStrings.IntroTermsService)</small></div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>


@section Scripts
{

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

}
```

My View includes all the necessary js files (jquery.validate and jquery.validate.unobtrusive)

Any ideas?!?

Comment: Do you have the `ClientValidationEnabled` settings as `true` in the web.config?

Comment: Any luck with this.  This is exactly what we're experiencing...was a consequence of our MVC5 upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue - the ValidationMessageFor() spans were rendering fine, but the data-val* attributes on the input fields were nowhere to be seen. Everything was working perfectly until we updated a host of NuGet packages last week.

We are using NInject with FluentValidation, to provide some custom validators for specific areas of our application. Hidden away in the binding for these custom validators is the following line:-

```
kernel.Unbind<ModelValidatorProvider>();
```

We commented this line out, and the data-val* attributes are back, and everything is fantastic again.

This seems obvious in hindsight, but it only came to light when we upgraded all NuGet packages recently (primarily to upgrade from MVC 5.0.0.0 to MVC 5.2.0.0 and WebApi 2.2). Along the way, a lot of other packages got upgraded, including FluentValidation and NInject.

This line of code hadn't changed, so it's possible that the behaviour of NInject has changed between version 3.0 and 3.2, as it all worked fine before the update.

My advice - check your IoC bindings because it is likely that somewhere you are intercepting the default model validation behaviour.

Comment: Thank you so much for the hint, I had a very similar issue. in my web application, there were two references to the DI, Ninject and LightInject. as I was just using LightInject and getting rid of the Ninject seems to fix the issue.

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is in your controller insert the following code. What it does is validates whether all the requirements in the Model have been meet.

```
    public ActionResult Register(Models.MyModel Model)
    { 
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
      }
    }
```

Comment: This does not answers the question! The OP problem is that the validation attributes are not rendered in the view in the HTML, it has nothing to do what the OP has in the controller.

Comment: Sorry I miss understood your question. Have you thought of ignoring c# razor and instead inserting the direct html input code you want to the html page?

Comment: The problem is in the rendering done by the helpers. This is really weird. I have no EditorTemplates for strings, but it looks like something different goes on in this project when it comes to render input fields